# Will the redirect to the same local port cause an infinite loop?

Tags: iptables

The rule:

`-t nat -A OUTPUT -m addrtype --src-type LOCAL --dst-type LOCAL -p tcp --dport 12345 -j DNAT --to-destination "127.0.0.1:12345"`

Will it loop? Is it well defined? How to avoid the looping (if any)?

My script generates the rule like this (and it would be good to not to have 127.0.0.1 as an exception):

`-t nat -A OUTPUT -m addrtype --src-type LOCAL --dst-type LOCAL -p tcp --dport 12345 -j DNAT --to-destination "$addr:12345"`

Comment: I don't know but I don't think the Linux Kernel would fool itself such an easy way. Very interesting question, I'll add it to my favorites indeed. You may also edit the post specifying what's the purpose of such a rule.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean "*Will it loop*"? The rule will be executed more than once?

The rule will not be revisited (re-checked) when it is matched by a packet. So, how is it possible to loop? Also, NAT rules will be checked only at the beginning of connection (connection establishment). Later, all packets will be handled by connection tracking module to apply the same already matched rule.

If you are still in doubt, you can see how many times a rule is matched using:

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -L -n -v
```